# Linux Crontab: doing no effect

Tags: linux, centos, cron

Have made backup script that does well: makes backup zip-file and then uploads it via ftp to another server. It's located here: `/home/www/web5/backup/backup`

Then I decided to put this script into crontab to be done automatically.
I'm doing (as root)

```
crontab -e
```

On the blank row I put:

> */1 * * * * /home/www/web5/backup/backup

```
Escape key, :wq!, Enter
```

I set it to be done each minute to test it.
Then went to the FTP folder, where script uploads the files. I'm waiting, but nothing happens: catalog is empty after each refresh in my Total Commander.

But when I execute `/home/www/web5/backup/backup` manually (as root as well), it works just fine and I see the new file at FTP.

What's wrong? This server is kind of heritage, so I might know not everything about it. Where to check first? OS is

> Linux s090 2.6.18.8-0.13-default

(kind of very old CentOS).
Thanks for any help!

UPD: `/home/www/web5/backup/backup` has chmod 777
UPD2: /var/log/cron doesn't exist. But /var/log/ directory exists and contains logs of apache, mail, etc.

Comment: When I have problems like this, it is usually because some environment variable (like, say, `PATH`) is different under cron than under the interactive shell.  If your cron does not Email a log to root, try appending `2>&1 >/tmp/backup.log` so you can see any output/errors from the script.

Comment: Logs should appear in /var/log/syslog or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*/1 may be the problem.  Just use *.

```
* * * * * /home/www/web5/backup/backup
```

Also, make sure `/home/www/web5/backup/backup` is executable with `chmod 775 /home/www/web5/backup/backup`

Check `/var/log/cron` as well.  That may show errors leading to a fix.

---

From [Crontab – Quick Reference](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

> - Crontab Environment
>
> cron invokes the command from the user’s HOME
>   directory with the shell, (/usr/bin/sh). cron supplies a default
>   environment for every shell, defining:
>
> ```
> HOME=user’s-home-directory
> LOGNAME=user’s-login-id
> PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:.
> SHELL=/usr/bin/sh
> ```
>
> Users who desire to have their .profile executed must explicitly do so
>   in the crontab entry or in a script called by the entry.

Comment: well, `/1` is not a division in the first place. At best it _resembles_ a modulo operation (but really, it isn't because POSIX allows e.g. `3/4` meaning `3,7,11,15...`

Comment: @sehe You are correct, crontab syntax is tough and people misinterpret the /n to be divison so I thought I would reference it in that way to make a point, but accuracy is probably a better idea.  Fixed answer.

Comment: @ABTMOT Do an ls in /var/log/ to see if any file/directory with the word cron exists, it might not be named exactly cron, it may be cron.log or cron/crontab.log, etc.

Comment: Logs seemed to be disabled. I've found it out when was reading syslog config file. After I enabled it it script started work. Thak everyone for help.

Comment: Very cool, glad you got this resolved @ABTOMAT!  If you dont mind sharing, what did the logs say that lead you to a fix?

Comment: Quote: "what did the logs say that lead you to a fix?" - I mean I saw in config that logs were disabled for cron. Just that. I enabled logs - and it worked.